# lua sort table by values

Tags: lua, roblox-studio

how can I easily sort this table by keys? it is necessary that it displays not a key and a value, but a sorted table

for example

```
local mytable = {
    ["name10"] = 6,
    ["name9"] = 10,
    ["name8"] = 8,
    ["name7"] = 4,
    ["name6"] = 1,
    ["name5"] = 7, 
    ["name4"] = 2,
    ["name3"] = 3,
    ["name2"] = 5,
    ["name1"] = 9
}
```

it needs to return this

```
local sorted_table = {
    ["name9"] = 10,
    ["name1"] = 9,
    ["name8"] = 8,
    ["name5"] = 7,
    ["name10"] = 6,
    ["name2"] = 5,
    ["name7"] = 4,
    ["name3"] = 3,
    ["name4"] = 2,
    ["name6"] = 1
}
```

i was looking for a solution to this problem, but everywhere it gave out exactly the key and the value separately, not the table

Comment: Your `sorted_table` is sorted by value in descending order. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, it needs to return sorted_table

Comment: Tables with keys do not have an order, you would need an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make list, not table as :

```lua
local mytable = {
    {name = "name10", value = 6},
    [name = "name9", value = 10},
    [name = "name8", value = 8},
}
```

and then sort it as usually:

```lua
function compareValuesBackwards(a,b)
  return a.value > b.value
end
table.sort(items, compareValuesBackwards)
```